# Is autonomy as the right to act rationally and freely really a goal in Romanticism?

Tags: romanticism

Is autonomy as the right to act rationally and freely really a goal in Romanticism?

In the [SE](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aesthetics-19th-romantic/index.html#Auto), autonomy is seen as an important value in German romanticism, and the definition of it by the romantics that is given is the one, rational and tempered, of Schlegel:

> While the absolute reality of freedom might not admit of a proof, according to many of the romantics, human beings should nonetheless approximate freedom by developing autonomy—self-determination and self-legislation. Autonomy is the right of the individual to think for herself and act rationally and freely (TPL II: 155).

TPL II = Schlegel, F., “Philosophical Lectures: Transcendental Philosophy, Part II”, in Beiser 1996. [TPL II]

If it is the case that autonomy in German romanticism is "the right of the individual to think for herself and act rationally and freely", then why did romanticism develop many themes and ideas at odds with this rational and tempered view of freedom such as:

- spleen,
- *ennui*,
- *Weltschmerz*,
- *le mal du siècle*,
- the (misanthrop, isolated, melancholic, alienated) romantic hero,
- *le poète maudit* (= "the race that will always be cursed by the powerful ones of the earth", Vigny 1832),
- extremely sentimental figures such as in *Julie; or, The New Heloise* (Rousseau) and *The Sorrows of Young Werther* (Goethe)?
- obscure mysticism (William Blake)